# ArcGIS Explorer Desktop configurations toolbars and panels too small

Tags: toolbar, arcgis-explorer, panel

I have just started working with ArcGIS Explorer and all the toolbars and panels fonts are too small and some are not completely visible. It looks like a screen configuration problem. It is possible to resolve this situation?[image]

Comment: Try changing the monitor resolution.

Comment: The last version of ArcGIS Explorer Desktop was released in 2013 and was [retired 4 years ago](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-explorer-desktop-blog/arcgis-explorer-desktop-retired-10-1-2017/ba-p/883791).  It probably doesn't work properly with modern high DPI displays.  You can change your display resolution, but that will affect all applications.

Comment: Thank both! I altered the display resolution but didn't work properly